# Chrome App : How to update the content of an element of a secondary window created in the main window of a Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, sandbox

i want to create a simple chrome App which launches a window, 'window.html', which contains 2 buttons.

```
1/ #btn1 creates a new window, loading "video.html". A video player,
playing "file1.webm".

2/ #btn2 updtates the source of the video from "file1.webm" to
"file2.webm".
```

The first part is trivial :)

The second part is tricky.

**Is it possible ?**

You'll find my files below.

Thank you :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

 <title>Chrome : Multiple Window</title>
 <link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn1" type="button" >Launch video Player</button>
 <button id="btn2" type="button" >Update Video</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btn1").click(function(){
 chrome.app.window.create('video_window.html', {"width":1280, "height": 720});
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  $('#myvideo video source').attr('src', './video/avatar.webm');
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="./css/video.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <video id="myvideo" autoplay loop>
   <source src="./video/the_master.webm" type="video/webm">
   </video>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.app.window.create` accepts a callback which will be invoked with the created window. You can store a reference to this window, and then either execute functions directly on it, or use `window.postMessage` to communicate with it.

```
var videoWindow = null;

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('video_window.html', {
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 720
  }, function(window) {
    videoWindow = window.contentWindow;
  });
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  videoWindow.doSomething('./video/avatar.webm');
});
```

Another option, is to use the [chrome runtime API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) to communicate:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("do-stuff")

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(e) {
    // do stuff
})
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for the first option and didn't found my way to get the id of the new window. Thank you very much !